# Default graphics

Tags: user-interface, ios

Is it possible to find the default graphics for UIBarButtonSystemItem as physical image files ?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure how to get the images out of the sdk but you can print them to disk via the iphone simulator. simply add whatever UIBarButtonSystemItem you want to a navigation bar and point its action to printImages

```
- (void)printImages {
  UIView *navbar = (UIView *)self.navigationController.navigationBar;
  for (UIView *v in navbar.subviews) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(v.layer.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [v.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *docPath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x.png", arc4random()]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage)];
    [imageData writeToFile:docPath atomically:YES];
  }
}
```

when you click on the button the images will be written to disk at ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/x.x/Applications/{crazy-guid-for-app}/Documents/

note: you will need `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and add the QuartzCore.framework to your application.